# Cloud9 offline mode

Tags: cloud9-ide

The first two links from a quick google search indicate that it's possible to work on a project via cloud9 while offline.

Is this possible to do, and has anyone had any experience with it? There doesn't seem to be anything mentioned in the docs.

I'm working on a chromebook and was hoping that this could be a possibility.

Thanks.

Note, the two links I found were:

- http://googlecode.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/working-offline-with-cloud9-on-google.html
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cbZBuxBdT24

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly this is not possible yet. There are new offline APIs being designed and we hope to make use of them in the future.

Comment: That's a shame. Do you know if there are eta's for these features? The links in my post are both from 2011.